# boolean value returns undefined on the client in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an asp.net core backend, where I get the data via api calls. I have this object model:

```
public class CostGroup
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public bool HcPlanning { get; set; }
    public bool OtherPlantCost { get; set; }
    public bool DirectLabCost { get; set; }
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And this api call:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public CostGroup GetCostGroup(long Id)
{
    return DataContext.CostGroups.Find(Id);
}
```

And this is the corresponding service in angular:

```
  getCostGroup(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<CostGroup>('api/masterdata/costaccounting/costgroups/' + id);
  }
```

Everything works, I get the result on the client side like this:

```
{"id":24,"name":"ss","rank":123,"hcPlanning":true,"otherPlantCost":true,"directLabCost":true,"companyId":1,"company":null}
```

As you see, the boolean values are correct recognized. But if I want to read the boolean values, I get undefined. I read the `CostGroup` object in angular like this:

```
this.service.getCostGroup(e.key).subscribe(costGroup => {
  this.costGroup = costGroup;
  this.companyId = costGroup.companyId;
  this.hcplanning = costGroup.hcplanning;
  this.otherplantcost = costGroup.otherplantcost;
  this.directlabcost = costGroup.directlabcost;
  alert(costGroup.directlabcost);
  this.editMode = true;
  this.name = costGroup.name;
  this.popup.instance.show();
});
```

All boolean fields are undefined. Why? How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object properties are in camel case:

```
"otherPlantCost":true
```

However you are accessing them in lower case:

```
this.otherplantcost = costGroup.otherplantcost;
```

You must access them correctly in camel case:

```
this.otherplantcost = costGroup.otherPlantCost;
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you.